# SQL - Select rows by entering two words

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains a field named Item_Name, which can be composed by one or more words.

> E.g. Item_Name -> Yellow Towel

I'd like to have a query that selects that value by entering "yel tow".
So far I've a query that selects that value by entering a single word

```
SELECT Item_Name FROM Articles WHERE Item_Name LIKE '%yel'
```

And it works fine.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: One way is: Cut your input string using index of space character. Cut your column value too, and use them in `LIKE` compare

Comment: Try this: SELECT Item_Name FROM Articles WHERE Item_Name LIKE 'yel% tow%'

Comment: `%` work in Access?  It should be `*` or did they change it some time after 2010?  Or is the tag wrong?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook yes, you're right I missclicked that tag. My bad sorry. 
As soon as I come back home I'll try them out.

Comment: `SELECT Item_Name FROM Articles WHERE Item_Name LIKE 'yel%' AND Item_Name LIKE '% tow%'` the question is how you split your search string. does it only have to work with 2 words or do you aim to make it work with any number of words entered?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should be what are you looking for, 
as your attempt is `like '%yel'`, I have used % at beginning as well

```
declare @search nvarchar(10) = 'yel tow'

declare @my_table table (test nvarchar(30))
insert into @my_table
values ('yellow towel'),
    ('y t'),
    ('yel tow'),
    ('random text')

select * from @my_table where test like '%' + replace(@search,' ', '%') + '%'
```

Output:

```
yellow towel
yel tow
```

Or straight forward select, as pointed in comments:

```
SELECT Item_Name FROM Articles WHERE Item_Name LIKE '%yel%tow%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

Create test data:

```
DECLARE @words NVARCHAR(40) = 'yel tow'  

CREATE Table #table (vals varchar(50))

INSERT INTO #table (vals) SELECT 'yellow towels'
```

**This is where the work happens**

```
SELECT *
FROM #table
WHERE vals like replace(@words,' ','% ')+'%'
```

Cleanup

```
DROP TABLE #table
```

Result Will be

```
yellow towels
```

So this should handle any number of words you throw at it. 
Note: The replace leaves the space so it will expect a space between each word.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following script

```
SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE Item_Name LIKE 'yel%' or Item_Name LIKE '% yel%'
```